# How to directly use Pandas Date-time index in calculations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that works:

```
table['CALC_DOM']=table.index
table['CALC_DOM']=table['END_DATE']-['CALC_DOM']
```

Shouldn't there be a better way to directly convert from table.index? like:

```
table['CALC_DOM']=table.index
table['CALC_DOM']=table['END_DATE']-(table.index())
```

I have tried using
`table.index.get_values`
and
`table.index.date`

...but all I get is:
`TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very close!

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(randn(5,2),index=date_range('20130101',periods=5))

In [3]: df['date'] = Timestamp('20130102')

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
                   0         1                date
2013-01-01  2.406932 -0.313473 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2013-01-02  0.034162 -0.708450 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2013-01-03 -1.585031  0.587243 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2013-01-04  1.454818  1.089208 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2013-01-05 -0.778016 -0.994242 2013-01-02 00:00:00

In [5]: df['td'] = df['date']-df.index.to_series()

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
                   0         1                date                td
2013-01-01  2.406932 -0.313473 2013-01-02 00:00:00  1 days, 00:00:00
2013-01-02  0.034162 -0.708450 2013-01-02 00:00:00          00:00:00
2013-01-03 -1.585031  0.587243 2013-01-02 00:00:00 -1 days, 00:00:00
2013-01-04  1.454818  1.089208 2013-01-02 00:00:00 -2 days, 00:00:00
2013-01-05 -0.778016 -0.994242 2013-01-02 00:00:00 -3 days, 00:00:00
```

Comment: I'm gonna keep at it 'till I get it! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: seems so obvious (but I couldn't get it)!

Comment: side note, I don't think to_series is documented in Index (which also is not highly documented either in doc-string or docs)?

Comment: actually now that I think about this, it could easily work directly...hmmmm